# How to make style of one active NavLink totally different from other active NavLinks?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-navigation

I have created all the navigation links using react-router-dom and NavLink.[image: screenshot of the header]

I want to give the cart icon a different style during active state from the other navigation items (i.e. Home, Contacts, About etc).I tried to make the cart active state different by giving its NavLink a different classname. But that didn't work. it takes the same style as other navigation elements.

```js
<nav >
        <li><NavLink activeClassName='active' exact to={'/'}>Home</NavLink> </li>
        <li><NavLink activeClassName='active' to={'about'}>About</NavLink> </li>
        <li><NavLink activeClassName='active' to={'contacts'}>Contact</NavLink> </li>
        <li><NavLink activeClassName='active' to={'products'}>Products</NavLink> </li>
        <li><NavLink activeClassName='active_cart' to={'cart'}><FaCartPlus /></NavLink></li>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your CSS/HTML, it's hard to say. It might be a CSS specificity issue.

That said, I recommend, instead of using a custom class to style the cart icon when currently on that page, to use the HTML attribute `[aria-current="page"]` that is specifically designed to designate that you're currently on a page:

```css
[role="menuitem"] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

[role="menuitem"][aria-current="page"] {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div role="menubar" aria-label="Main menu">
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" role="menuitem" aria-current="page">Cart</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On an unrelated note, looking at your above HTML, please make sure that your `<li>` are direct children of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element so that your HTML will validate.